# Is downloading a non-copyright paid video course illegal?

Tags: copyright

I have found an online video course that the user is selling for around $200, and it says on the website that the course is copyrighted in the footer. However, I have checked everywhere online but there is no mention of the copyright on the online libraries. I have found a URL that has this course available for download for free, but I am skeptical of downloading it since I feel I may be subjecting myself to piracy, but at the same time am unsure on the other end since there is no mention of any copyright on this course in the online libraries, which means the person who is claiming to have a copyright may be giving a false claim. What should be my course of action? Is it legal to download the course then?

Comment: We need context.  How did you discover this URL?

Comment: _there is no mention of the copyright on the online libraries_ - It is not required to mention the copyright. The person or company which created it, has copyright. I'll try to find another question with more information.